# What are some reputable, local operators offering day tours to Machhu Picchu from Cusco

Tags: peru, machu-picchu

We're travelling to Cusco this November looking to take the day trip offered to Machhu Pichhu. I have read that booking tours on the ground are more reasonable then when booked online.

My questions, for any one with anecdotal experiences, are:

1. What are the names of some tour operators you have pleasantly experienced? We have a 6 year old travelling with us, so the train is the most viable option.
2. Can we book the train ticket separately (via perurail.com) and then expect tour guides to walk us through Machhu Pichhu, upon our arrival?